# IDE recommendations for Python 3 on Windows 10 for a beginner?

Tags: windows, python, ide

I have just started to learn Python Syntax after learning most of the basics of OOP on Turbo C++. I only intend to create basic amateur-level programs and games and eventually dabble in Artificial Intelligence in games.

I am currently trying out PyCharm's Community Edition. I would like to know if there are other free IDEs worth taking a look at with good features(autocompletion of code), decent customisability and a clean UI.

Visual Studio is also frequently recommended but I am unsure if VS or VS Code would be a better option considering my simple requirements.

Comment: VS Code is really good with the python extensions. Entirely different software from Visual Studio.

Comment: That's what I read. I tried Visual Studio for C++ but the syntax varied a lot because I had learned much older syntax. VS Code would be lighter and less features I might not use preinstalled right?

Comment: Pycharm is a really great IDE. It's made for Python. VS Code is also ok, but it somehow looks like made for everything.

Comment: @ThomasWeller I've used both and I currently prefer VS Code. To each his own.

Answer (score 4):

Ones that I have tried and are Free & worth taking a look, in no specific order:

- [VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/) *with [Python extensions](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.python)*
- [PyCharm](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/) Community Edition
- [WingIDE](https://wingware.com/) 101/personal *(Personally I liked this enough that I shelled out for the pro edition)*
- [Spyder](https://www.spyder-ide.org/) *Included in Anaconda Distributions*
- [PyDev](https://www.pydev.org/) *Eclipse Plugin*
- [Eric IDE](https://eric-ide.python-projects.org/) *there is a pun in the [name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eric_Idle) if you know why python is called python*

A more complete but slightly dated list can be found at https://wiki.python.org/moin/IntegratedDevelopmentEnvironments

Not IDEs but I would always recommend taking a look at:

- [iPython](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) - interactive python shell with magics & autocomplete
- [Jupyter Notebooks](https://jupyter.org/) or [Jupyter Lab](https://jupyterlab.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) - Python *and other languages* mixed with markdown text in a web browser.

Comment: I'll try out all of these one by one.

Answer (score 0):

Since **Atom** has not been mentioned yet, here you go: https://atom.io/

Some benefits:

- cross-platform
- free and open-source
- extensive customization
- lots of packages (add-ons)
- not limited to the Python language

No experience with PyCharm so I can't really compare the two.